# Javascript iterate Json Array to get values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, ecmascript-6

I have a below JavaScript

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({0:'Zero'});
arr.push({1:'One'});
console.log(Object.keys(arr));
console.log(Object.values(arr)); //Not getting expected result
```

I want to print keys and values separately, could able to fetch keys but not able to get values.

Comment: You're pushing an object into each array index.  You'd need to access it by index, then by key/value.  Did you mean to create `var obj = {}` instead?  If that's the case, `push` wouldn't be used, you'd just set the key directly, e.g. `obj[0] = 'Zero'`, effectively creating `{ 0: 'Zero', 1: 'One' }` instead of `[ { 0: 'Zero' }, { 1: 'One' }...]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `arr` is an array, not an object. You should use `map` like so:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({0: 'Zero'})
arr.push({1: 'One'})
console.log(arr.map(e => Object.keys(e)).flat(1));
console.log(arr.map(e => Object.values(e)).flat(1));
```

I used `flat` to make the array flat, instead of it being nested.

Comment: Nice, but `.flat` cannot be considered reliable for cross-browser compatibility

Answer (score 3):

Here you're pushing `Objects` inside array so you need to access them using index.

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({0:'Zero'})
arr.push({1:'One'})

let values = arr.map((e,index)=> arr[index][Object.keys(e)[0]])
console.log(values)
```

***On side note:*** Both of your console is not working change the keys to anything else than `0 and 1` and see the output. In case of array `Object.keys` will return the index of array which `0, 1 and so on`

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({0:'Zero'})
arr.push({10:'One'})

console.log(Object.keys(arr))
```

Probably this is what you wanted to achieve. If this is the case than you need to use `{} ( Object )` instead of `[] ( Array )`

```js
var arr = {};
arr['0'] = 'Zero';
arr['1'] = 'One';

console.log(Object.keys(arr));
console.log(Object.values(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get the keys/values from your objects (in the form of an array) and then flatten the array into your result:

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push({0: 'Zero'})
arr.push({1: 'One'})

console.log(arr.flatMap(Object.keys));
console.log(arr.flatMap(Object.values));
```

However, please note, `.flatMap` is has [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) and so it may not work in all browsers. Instead, if you cannot use `.flatMap` and want a more stable solution you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push({0: 'Zero'});
arr.push({1: 'One'});

console.log(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => [...acc, Object.keys(obj).shift()], []));
console.log(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => [...acc, Object.values(obj).shift()], []));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objects on the array only have one `key` and one `value`, then you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) inside [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({0:'Zero'});
arr.push({1:'One'});

let keys = arr.map(o => Object.entries(o)[0][0]);
let values = arr.map(o => Object.entries(o)[0][1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(keys), JSON.stringify(values));
```

Otherwise, you could use the experimentals `flat()` or `flatMap()` like others have mentioned, or a version using `reduce()` like this one:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push({0:'Zero'});
arr.push({1:'One', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'});

let keys = arr.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc.concat(Object.keys(curr)),
    []
);

let values = arr.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc.concat(Object.values(curr)),
    []
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(keys), JSON.stringify(values));
```